# Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters

Tags: php, mysqli

Hola a todos estoy usando mysqli y tengo el siguiente error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match
>   number of parameters in prepared statement on line 8

Por favor si me pueden apoyar a resolverlo gracias :)

```
<?php

$conexion = new mysqli('localhost','','','');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) { echo mysqli_connect_error(); exit; }
    $q = "%" . $_POST['q'] . "%";
    $consulta= $conexion->prepare("SELECT ar.Titulo_Articulo, ar.Id_Articulo, r.Id_Revista FROM articulos as ar INNER JOIN revista as r on r.Id_Revista = 

ar.Id_Revista where ar.pdf LIKE ?");
    $consulta->bind_param("s", $q);
    $consulta->execute();
    $res = $consulta->get_result();
    if($conexion->affected_rows>0)
    {
      while($fila=$res->fetch_array())
        {

            echo '<a href="autenticacion.php?id='.$fila["Id_Revista"].'&articulo='.$fila["Id_Articulo"].'" width="50%" class="sugerencias" onclick="myFunction2('.utf8_encode($fila["Titulo_Articulo"]).')"><br>'.utf8_encode($fila['Titulo_Articulo']).'</a>';

        }
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<b>No hay sugerencias</b>';
    }
    $consulta->close();
    $conexion->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes son las comillas en el `like`: `LIKE '%?%'")`. Recibes ese error porque pones comillas simples, el `?` se interpreta entonces como una cadena literal y no como el marcador del parámetro que quieres hacer binding.

Además, esas comillas son innecesarias porque en el  `bind_param` ya estás indicando que va a ser un string (con la "s" del primer parámetro). La solución sería simple en dos pasos:

1. Concatena los símbolos de porcentaje antes de la sentencia. Por ejemplo, cuando lees el valor:

   ```
   $q = "%" . $_POST['q'] . "%";
   ```
2. Quita los porcentajes y las comillas en la consulta, simplificando el `like`:

   ```
   ... where ar.pdf LIKE ?
   ```

Con esos cambios el código interpreta el "?" como un marcador y te debería funcionar:

```
<?php

    $conexion = new mysqli('localhost','','','');
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) { echo mysqli_connect_error(); exit; }
    $q = "%" . $_POST['q'] . "%";
    $consulta= $conexion->prepare("SELECT ar.Titulo_Articulo, ar.Id_Articulo, r.Id_Revista FROM articulos as ar INNER JOIN revista as r on r.Id_Revista = ar.Id_Revista where ar.pdf LIKE ?");
    $consulta->bind_param("s", $q);
    $consulta->execute();
    if($conexion->affected_rows>0)
    {
      while($fila=$res->fetch_array())
        {

            echo '<a href="autenticacion.php?id='.$fila["Id_Revista"].'&articulo='.$fila["Id_Articulo"].'" width="50%" class="sugerencias" onclick="myFunction2('.utf8_encode($fila["Titulo_Articulo"]).')"><br>'.utf8_encode($fila['Titulo_Articulo']).'</a>';

        }
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<b>No hay sugerencias</b>';
    }
    $consulta->close();
    $conexion->close();
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta si yo le quito los % me deja de realizar la consulta, me entra a no hay sugerencias

Comment: ¿Pones los % al leer el valor de $_POST['q']?

Comment: si lo tengo igual

Comment: He mirado mi código, me funciona con `$res = $consulta->get_result();` justo después del `execute()`, ¿has probado eso?

Comment: he actualizado y sigue igual

Comment: el error es Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP usas?¿Tienes el driver mysqlnd?

Comment: si tengo mysqlnd instalado mi versión es 5.5.34

Comment: ¿Y si corres la SELECT en la base de datos directamente funciona? Copio el código de la pregunta en local, le cambio la consulta a algo parecido (aunque no igual) y sí me funciona sin errores.

Comment: si me funciona la consulta

Comment: pero funciona asi LIKE  '%h%'

Comment: Sinceramente, no sé por qué ocurre ese nuevo error. Parece más algún problema de configuración en el servidor

Comment: :( ya llevo asi un buen tiempo y nadie sabe XD gracias por el apoyo

Comment: hola a todos actualizo el contenido, el código era correcto pero a pesar de tener el driver no lo tenía habilitado en apache, tuve que reiniciar el servicio y funciona. Gracias

Comment: @QuirozLuis me alegro que encontraras la solución. Al final sí que era un problema de configuración :-)